# Sparse Matrix Vs Dense Matrix Multiplication C++ Tensorflow

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I would like to write in C++ Tensorflow sparse matrix dense vector (SPMv) multiplication: y = Ax

The sparse matrix, A, is stored in CSR format. The usual sparsity of A is between 50-90%. The goal is to reach *better or similar time* than that of dense matrix dense vector (DMv) multiplication.

Please note that I have already viewed the following posts: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584588/dense-sparse-matrix-multiplication-routine-instead-if-sparse-dense-multiplicatio) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591879/matrix-vector-multiplication-sparse-vs-dense-matrices) [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969506/sparse-matrix-vector-multiplication-in-cuda). However, I still am wondering about the following:

1. How does SPMv multiplication compare in terms of time to DMv? Since sparsity is relatively high, I assume that SPMv should be better given the reduction in the number of operations - Yes?
2. What should I take into to account to make SpMv the same or better in terms of time than the DMv? Why ppl are saying that the DMv will perform petter than SPMv? Does the storage representation make a difference?
3. Any recommended libraries that do SPMv in C++ for either CPU or GPU implementation.

This question is relevant to my other question here: ([CSCC: Convolution Split Compression Calculation Algorithm for Deep Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130176/cscc-convolution-split-compression-calculation-algorithm-for-deep-neural-networ))

Comment: Sparcity of 50% isn't worth using any sparce matrix format. To make it worthwhile it needs to be much less like 1%.

Comment: @HossamAmer Sparse formats require *at least* storing a column or row index per entry as well as the entry. So assuming 32 bit indices and values that is a factor > 2 for storage. And the data is less regular and harder on the cache (also you probably lose vectorization).

Comment: @Joe Thanks! I edited my question, Let's just focus only on time... I would like my execution time to be better than DMv

I have seen the following [link](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/3-C/sparse.html) that explains CSR multiplication - Even with this algorithm therein, the time will be worse? I think that memory access is contiguous and cache-friendly + less # of (add & multiply) ops - no?

Comment: Welcome to SO; regarding your 3rd question, please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Okay noted-  thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer the edited question:

1. Unless the Matrix is very sparse (<10% nonzeros on CPU, probably <1% on GPU), you will likely not benefit from the sparsity. While the number of floating point operations is reduced, the amount of storage is *at least* double (column or row index + value), memory access is irregular (you have an indirection via the index for the right-hand side), it becomes far more difficult to vectorize (or to achieve coalescing on the GPU) and if you parallelize you have to deal with the fact that rows are of varying length and therefore a static schedule is likely to be suboptimal.
2. Beyond the points above, yes, the storage representation matters. For example a COO-matrix stores *two* indices and the value, while CSR/CSC only store one but require an additional offset array which makes them more complex to build on the fly. Especially on the GPU, storage formats matter if you want to at least achieve *some* coalescing. This paper looks into how storage formats affect performance on the GPU: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/cgf.13957
3. For something generic try [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) or [cuSparse](https://developer.nvidia.com/cusparse) on GPU. There are plenty of others that perform better for specific use cases, but this part of the question isn't clearly answerable.

Beyond the matrix format itself, even the ordering of entries in your matrix can have a massive impact on performance, which is why the Cuthill-McKee algorithm is often used to reduce matrix bandwidth (and thereby improve cache performance).

Comment: The amount of NZEs range from 10-50% in my A.

Comment: Ok, your second comment on the question it sounded like you hat 50-90% NZEs. For the ones closer to 10% you *may* benefit from sparse matrices but for those closer to 50% you definitely won't. Neither w.r.t. performance or memory use.

Comment: The amount of NZEs ranges from 10-50% in my A. The size of A is relatively huge.

CPU case => With the sparsity about 50-90% and CSR product algorithm in this [link](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/3-C/sparse.html), you think that DMv will still be better? Can you please point out the irregular memory access? Why is it difficult to vectorize? 

GPU case => Yes! There will be rows of varying length - Will it be worse than DMv? Can it be close in terms of time?

I am trying to reproduce this paper's results  [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8723509)?

Comment: `d[Col[k]]` causes irregular memory access and is also part of the reason vectorization is difficult. The other part is the varying loop bounds `k = RowPtr[i]; k < RowPtr[i+1]`. Especially on GPU, I doubt you'll see any benefit from SpMV, but if in doubt: measure.

Comment: Thanks, Joe - How can I measure? Are their recommended ways to measure in C++?

Comment: Just use timers (monotonic and high precision!) and/or query events. `std::chrono` works fine. Far more important is that you measure with real data and ideally measure the entire process in context (no microbenchmarks with synthetic data!).

Comment: Yes, I understand this of course - I meant that which C++ sparse library I should use to test this? Should I implement the algorithm therein myself? Are there pre-defined matrix multiplication libraries?

Comment: Several, as mentioned in my answer. For CPU, `Eigen::SparseMatrix` works fine, though you may need to set `Eigen::RowMajor` and enable paralellization for best performance.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if parallelization is handled by Eigen or I should handle it myself using normal C++ multi-threading?

__About the irregular memory access__, do you mean that elements are not accessed in order? Can you please give me a definition for this?


__For GPU__, do you think that it's possible that we at least reach similar performance as in the DMv?

Comment: Eigen supports parallelization directly (albeit only for a small subset of functions). Obviously, how irregular (non-sequential) `d[Col[k]]` is depends on the contents of `Col`. Which in fact makes the situation worse, as you also now have a data dependency, i.e. you have to load `Col[k]` before you can even begin loading `d[Col[k]]`, which massively increases latency. Re GPU performance: Maybe for the ones around 10%, but for the rest: highly unlikely.

Comment: Thanks Joe so much - What will you say if I tell you that my vector `d` is usually small in size in my problem setting? d could have a size of 64 (8x8) at most?

Comment: So you have many rows but few columns? That is very helpful for CSR performance (you could store your entire right hand side in shared memory).

Comment: My sparse matrix in dense format is much much bigger than `d` of size `N=64 or 8x8`. Each NZE in `Val` in CSR representation needs to be multiplied by all elements in `d` of size `N` to produce the result.
So, yes I think that it is possible to store the vector `d` in shared memory for the GPU case. What is the right-hand side?
Based on this, what do you say about the CPU case? For both CPU and GPU, does the impact of the amount of NZE will now be less severe? PS: I am writing the code, but your comments are very helpful :)

Comment: Right Hand side = d. (As in Ad, d is on the right). In principle with so few elements you could store 8 bit indices, making the whole thing more compact. For the CPU d will fit into L1, so the impact of the irregular access is probably negligible. Try it :)

Comment: I did some implementation as you suggested- Could you please give me your insight on my follow-up question here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63331049/efficient-csr-sparse-matrix-dense-vector-multiplication-in-c-tensorflow-using